# Facebook public post crawling using R: get the Public Posts at Certain Facebook Page

Tags: r, facebook, post

I have been trying to get the public posts to the certain facebook page, for example(This page: https://www.facebook.com/pg/Instacart/community/?ref=page_internal), but failed to do so. All I can get is the posts that published by the page owner.

Can someone help to point out what went wrong? I was hoping to get the posts as shown in the graph. [Public posts at Instacart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQjTR.png)

I used R and the code below.

```html
Instacart_feed <- getPage(page = "Instacart",token = token, n = 1500, feed = TRUE)
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90-pages - you don't get user-related stuff any more unless you use a page token for that page.

Comment: thanks for this. @CBroe.  But if I am using R to crawl, how can I get the page token for that page?

Comment: Needs page admin access to begin with. If you have that - then go check the documentation, on how to obtain a page token.